# Directory link for full-text directories only

Tags: ibm-domino

**Question**: Is it possible to redirect full-text index (FTI) directories created along with mail file databases to different drive?

Company does not want to spend more money on SANs for Domino server. Lack of space was solved by limiting FTIs to specific users only. The rest of them are upset.

I see the solution in putting FTI directories to cheaper disks (in case of failure FTI can be easily reconstructed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Domino server is 8.5.3 or higher you can use `FTBasePath` notes.ini variable to [set the location of full text indexes](http://blog.nashcom.de/nashcomblog.nsf/dx/full-text-index-on-separate-drive.htm).

Comment: [FTBasePath](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory/27-indexing/3507-ftbasepath.html) is what we use here as well. Another option to save space would be "Design Compression" and [DAOS](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/categories/notes-domino/158-sntt-enabling-daos-and-some-considerations.html?showall=1&limitstart=) by the way.